FingerPrint Sensor for Ubuntu 24.04
lsusb gives
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader

on my HP ProBook 450 G3 laptop, but then fprintd-enroll shows the following message
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

This is after installing dependencies using the following command.
sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd


What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Tried installing dependencies
$$$ sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd

Please add that to the question.
